# Find last records in table by FK

Tags: sql, postgresql

My table looks like:

```
id
caseid
status
```

Example data in the table:

```
1   10    open
2   10    published
3   10    reopened
4   11    open
5   11    contact
6   11    response
7   11    published
```

I need to get all `caseid`s where the last status was `published`.

So in the above example only `11` would be retrieved (because the caseid 10 was reopenend later).

What would the query look like?

PS

I'm using PDO with prepared statements.

Answer (score 4):

```
select caseid from data d1 where d1.status = 'published' 
and not exists (select * from data d2 where d1.caseid = d2. caseid
and d2.id > d1.id)
```

For best performance, the id and caseid columns should be indexed.

Answer (score 3):

```
select a.caseid
from
  (select max(id) as id, caseid
  from table
  group by caseid)a  --this would get the last entry for every caseid
  inner join table b on (a.id=b.id) 
where b.status = 'published'
```

Comment: I get an error when I run this query: `select caseid from (select max(id) as id, caseid from statuses group by caseid)a inner join statuses b on (a.id=b.id) where b.status = 'published'`. Error: `Warning: PDOStatement::execute() [pdostatement.execute]: SQLSTATE[42702]: Ambiguous column: 7 ERROR: column reference "caseid" is ambiguous LINE 1: select caseid from (select max(id) as id, caseid from status... ^ in`. I changed the table to my table name or wasn't that correct?

Comment: @PeeHaa - Change your `SELECT` to `SELECT a.caseid`

Comment: Great this works! Thanks. However the answer of @Elroy Flynn also seem to work. Which one is the best and why?

Comment: That will depend on several things, like your table structure, indexes, etc. You can compare the execution plan for both and see wich one fits better to your data. Also, you can take a look at this article by @Quassnoi http://explainextended.com/2009/06/16/in-vs-join-vs-exists/

Comment: IMHO, I'd say that my answer is probably better, since it a) is not as complex (at least in my mind) and b) does not require grouping , and so may be more performant.   But as noted, YMMV.  If you examine the query plan for each, the answer may be revealed.

Comment: or, if they seems equal to you, you can accept the first in time :)

Comment: @Lamak: your link is for SQL server, while we are talking PostgreSQL here. So, not fully applicable.

Answer (score 1):

EDITED:

Sorry - brain fart the first time around :(

Is this better?

```
select a.caseid,a.status
from temp a
where a.id in
  (select MAX(id) maxid from temp group by caseid)
  and status='published'
```

Comment: your solution does not address the requirement that the selected row appear "later" (have higher id) than all others for the case.

Comment: @PeeHaa - or equivalently: `select caseid
from temp
where id in
  (select MAX(id) from temp group by caseid)
  and status='published'`  PS: I saw the beginning of "A Clockwork Orange" on Dish TV this morning.  The scene where Alex and his droogs mercilessly kick and stomp the bum.  Kinda' reminds me of SO sometimes... ;)

Comment: Now I reversed my -1 and gave you a +1

Comment: @Lamak - Thanx!  Mucho appreciated!  And appy-polly-logies for my original (dumb!) reply.

Answer (score 1):

I'll add another query, because it is the **fastest one without indexes** - it only requires a single sequential table scan. Simpler and faster than @Florin's query.

```
SELECT caseid
FROM   tbl
GROUP  BY caseid
HAVING max(id) = max(CASE WHEN status = 'published' THEN id ELSE NULL END);
```

---

However, **with proper indexes @Elroy's solution is a lot faster**. I actually ran a quick benchmark with a similar real life table to verify this.
Proper indexes:

```
CREATE INDEX tbl_id_idx ON tbl (id);
```

And this [partial index](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/indexes-partial.html) for optimal results:

```
CREATE INDEX tbl_status_published_idx ON tbl (id) WHERE status = 'published';
```

You don't need any other indexes for this query. In particular, an additional index on `caseid` is of no use. Always consider that index maintenance carries a cost, too - especially if the table is heavily written.

This will probably change with covering indexes ("index-only scans") in PostgreSQL 9.2. I wrote [more about that in a recent answer on dba.SE](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/7541/3684).

Try [EXPLAIN ANALYZE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-explain.html) to verify.